# MongoDB - lookup/taxonomies

Tags: mongodb

In my MongoDB database I have a number of document types that require look-up/taxonomy information.  Typically I'm either holding an Id of the look-up or an Id and denormalising the look up info into the main document.

e.g.

```
task = { 
   TaskDetail : "Some task",
   TaskPriority : { Id : xxxxx, Code : 'U', Description:'Urgent' }
}
```

Moving from traditional relational databases (RDBMS) where I would just have a `TaskPriority` table, I was wondering what the best practice is when using documents within mongo?

My initial thought was to have a taxonomy/look-up collection.  Typically, look-up and enums are short, so each could be a separate document in the collection?  Or I could mirror what you'd typically do in a RDBMS database and create a collection to look-up?

Can anybody point in me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: I'd be tempted to have a separate collection to store all of your task priorities.  This would contain id, code and description.  In your task document I'd just have the id.  Although this sounds quite like an RDBMS route is does avoid duplicating what would typically (educated guess) be static data and thus provide little value stored in every document.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing has advantages such as :

1. Better management of master data
2. De-duplication, hence lesser updates.

disadvantages :

1. look-up is a separate API call, no joins in MongoDB
2. $DBRef of $lookup functions can still be used, but cumbersome. Manual reference is easier.
3. Atomicity in document level, hence look-up in collections can get out of sync for sometime if the reference look-up collection is updated.

Embedding - 
On the other hand embedding does not make sense for reference data, since in case the look-up value gets updated, you need to update all your documents. That is a huge exercise to keep a track of all the documents and their keys which needs reference data updates.

Secondly embedding of reference data, also can not achieve SCD (slowly changing dimension) history keeping ability. If the referencing is used instead, you can achieve this with a version date in the reference collection.

Considering these points, I am inclined to referencing. But my only doubt is if I do not have the referenced value in my parent documents, how will search work? When a user search with descriptive referenced values, how mongo will refer to the reference data collection?